# How can I buy bitcoins using Western Union (October 2012)?

Tags: exchanges

I would like to use Western Union to buy some Bitcoins. I have carefully read [Bitcoin's wiki page about buying Bitcoins](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins) now I'm after users' input about which service they would recommend. 
There's a lot of services and I am just after the quickest and safest (like everyone I guess). Could, you guys, recommend a service you find to be the best please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Western Union is a hassle and is expensive.   Bitcoins Direct was accepting WU payments until just a couple days ago.  In the U.S., about the last exchange to accept WU (USD) for bitcoins is:

- http://www.QuickBitcoins.net

In the EU there is an exchange that accepts WU (EUR):

- http://bitcoinsinberlin.com

There are also some others.  For instance:

- http://www.ecurrencyzone.net/buy.php
- http://www.coinmama.com

As far as other options, the factors relevant to providing the right advice include:

- Where are you located (country)?
- How much are you looking to buy?
- What payment methods do you have available?
- How soon do you need access to the proceeds?
- Is privacy important?

Quite simply, depositing cash at a bank or 7-11, Walmart, CVS is going to be the fastest and easiest way.

Options:

- http://www.BitInstant.com (Deposit at major banks, 7-11, Walmart, CVS, Moneygram, etc.,)
- http://www.BitMe.com (Deposit cash at Chase)
- http://www.BitFloor.com (Deposit cash at Chase or Wells Fargo)
- http://www.bitinnovate.com (Deposit cash at a bank in Australia & New Zealand)
- http://www.CAVirtEx.com (Deposit cash at several banks)
- http://www.Spendbitcoins.com (Deposit cash at a bank in Australia)
- http://BitcoinNordic.com (Purchase CashU or UKash in dozens of countries)
- http://www.BTC-E.com (Deposit cash (USD) at bank locations in Russia)
- http://www.BitNZ.om (Deposit cash (NZD) at back locations in New Zealand)
- http://www.BitInstant.com (In Brazil using Boleto or Banco Recomendito, or in Russia, using Qiwi or Cyberplat.)

Also, Bitcoins Direct will accept cash, but they have a $500 minimum order size:

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=87094.0 (Deposit cash at Bank of America, Wells Fargo or PNC, minimum $500)

Or you might find a local trade (paying cash):

- http://www.localbitcoins.com

The fees aren't trivial but you can use a credit card to purchase by using VirWoX where you can buy SLL using your credit card, then trade SLL for BTC:

- http://www.VirWoX.com

Or if you are considering a bank transfer, there all kinds of options are available:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins

There is also #bitcoin-otc where you can connect with sellers via IRC:

- http://bitcoin-otc.com/

Buying  bitcoin with western union westernuniontobitcoins.com  is very easy, being one of the few that allows you to transfer money online directly to  bank account or to a person authorized to raise money from an office W.U

- http://westernuniontobitcoins.com

Comment: Thank you for extensive reply. This really does help ! And in your reply I have found what I couldn't even imagine existing where I live (Paris, France): cash for BTC exchangers (your link http://localbitcoins.com) which is absolutely perfect since I have found a guy living really close to mine. So I have contacted him and I'll just go to his place with my laptop, exchange cash for BTC at a very nice rate (more or less Mtgox's) which is absolutely perfect. It's instant, anonymous, quick and free of fees. 
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You probably will have the best luck on [Bitcoin OTC](http://bitcoin-otc.com/vieworderbook.php). It's a service allowing you to trade person-to-person, so you can use any means that someone else will find acceptable.

Comment: Great, I like the idea. Thank you for the heads up ! I guess one could easily get scammed though.

Comment: @user2021 That's why there is otc rating. Pick your risk wisely based on it.